# Shinken Monitoring - how to configure service checks on a host, for a specific time of the day

Tags: monitoring, nagios, shinken

We are using **Shinken Framework** for monitoring our servers, in that I got a scenario like I want to execute a service check only once in a day that is everyday at **1 AM**, how can I configure it?

*Using **check_interval** or **time_period** can we achieve this..?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `check_interval` and `check_period`.
For example, we are using check at 9 AM everyday for check system updates. Just change time and service for your needs.

```
define timeperiod {
  timeperiod_name                morning_check
  alias                          morning_check
  monday                         09:00-09:01
  tuesday                        09:00-09:01
  wednesday                      09:00-09:01
  thursday                       09:00-09:01
  friday                         09:00-09:01
  saturday                       09:00-09:01
  sunday                         09:00-09:01
}

define service {
  service_description            updates
  host_name                      Docker
  use                            svc-pnp,local_standard_mail
  check_command                  ext_nrpe!check_updates!null
  check_period                   morning_check
  check_interval                 1440
  max_check_attempts             1
  notification_interval          1440
}
```

Comment: @Rohit I want to retry this service check upon failures, say retry 3 times with interval 5 
so should I increase the time limit to 09:00-09:20..?

Comment: @user2264738: Yep, Increase the time limit, change `max_check_attempts` to `3` and `retry_interval` to `5` and you are done.